# Including carriage returns in PHP regex

Tags: php, regex

How do I rewrite the following regex expression to include carriage returns and spaces?

```
mysql_query\("(.*)"\)
```

It should match the following types of data.

String with carriage returns:

```
$result = my_mysql_query("
SELECT foo, bar
FROM mytable
ORDER BY name");
```

String with some carriage returns:

```
$result = my_mysql_query("SELECT foo, bar
FROM mytable
ORDER BY name");
```

String with no carriage returns:

```
$result = my_mysql_query("SELECT foo, bar FROM mytable ORDER BY name");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use PCRE (used by PHP's `preg_*()` functions), use the `s` modifier so `.` matches carriage returns and newlines:

```
/mysql_query\("(.*)"\)/s
```

Comment: I will be using PHP's preg_match.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question... The better regex is:

```
/mysql_query\("(.?)"\)/s
```